# Views relationship between user and custom created entity

Tags: 8, views

I've an custom entity type : "*card*", witch has a property named "*owner*", an `entity_reference` to the owner of the card.

My custom entity is pretty basic and has been created trough Drupal Console.

If I create a view on *Cards* I can use the relationship to get the "owner" fields and properties accessible.

But if on a  *Users* based view, the reverse relationship is not present : I can't access card information's from the owner.

Am-I missing something ? Do I have to set up this *reverse relationship* somewhere ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok ! finally found out !

I had to use the hook_views_data_alter to put the relationship on the user :

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_data_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_views_data_alter(array &$data) {
  $data['users_field_data']['cards'] = [
    'title' => t("Users cards"),
    'help' => t("Link the users to their cards"),
    'relationship' => [
      'group' => t('Cards'),
      'label' => t("User cards"),
      'base' => 'cards', // database table
      'base field' => 'owner', //database field to join on
      'relationship field' => 'uid',
      'id' => 'cards',
    ],
  ];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just a note, for the `id` key, I used the value `standard` for the standard relationship plugin handling, then it worked.